# how OpenCv indexing works?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCv and numpy and I have a problem figuring out how OpenCv indexing works

so first I am reading an image using this piece of code

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(im_address)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print("img size is {}".format(img.shape))
```

and the output is

```
(1280, 960)
```

where 1280 is the height and 960 is the width,but when I try to draw a line in the image using following line I get a vertical line except a horizontal line

```
cv2.line(img, (98, 0), (98, 1279), (0, 0, 125), 2)
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 700, 500)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

does OpenCv treat the first index of any coordinate as width? or I am missing something?

Comment: From the docs it looks like Points are described as (x,y) NOT (height,width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OpenCV treats the first and second coordinates as horizontal and vertical respectively. Specifically, the first coordinate traverses the columns and the second traverses the rows.

Comment: tnks, I was a little confused because img type is numpy.ndarray

Comment: @salmanrezaie Yeah, this is a result of keeping with their `cv::Mat` type.  The nomenclature there is to do width, height.  NumPy arrays do height, width.